# Set Play Framework Environment

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a problem with a project deploy. Until now, I was using a single playframework app, running listening port 80.
Now, I have published in the same server 2 apps, using Nginx as a proxy. Nginx listening in port 80 and the apps runs in port 9001 and 9002.

All works well, but the apps running in dev mode and not in prod mode, the page 404 does't work, and in html page I see the code error like this: "Action not found For request 'GET /asd'".
I run the app with this command:

myapp -Dhttp.port=9001 -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf -Dlogger.file=/mydir/conf/application-logger.xml -Dpidfile.path=/mydir/daasy.pid -server

I use playframework 2.4.3 with scala 2.11.7

**Update:**
I have created a bootstrap class:

```
class onStartClass @Inject() (val app: Application)
{
  println(app.mode)
}
```

The app.mode return "Prod" when run in prod, with port 80 and also when run in port 9001.

But, when the app run in port 9001 doesn't work the page 404, the website return a playframework error page.

Comment: how do you package/deploy your app ?

Comment: @Jean with dist, then I put the zip in the server, unzip and start.

Comment: You could use curl to check if your two apps work without your proxy. Just specify the port 9001 or 9002, e.g. `curl http://youraddress.com:9001/asd`.

Comment: @Kris, yes I can, is a test then I made. The apps works, but works in Dev mode, I can access with the port 9001 and 9002.

Comment: @faster2b Sorry, I have trouble understanding. You say, your 2 apps work well in dev mode but not in prod mode?

Comment: @Kris, sorry for my bad explication, it's a bit complicate to explain :). The problem is than the applications thinks to stay in "Dev enviroment" when I put it in production. Play framework has 3 mode of work: dev, test and prod. In dev enviroment doesn't work pages 404 and others things. If i run the app in the port 80, the app return to work in "prod mode".

Comment: @Kris an example: when the app run in dev mode I try to go in an no exist url and play framework show me an error: Action not found For request 'GET /adasd'  But, in prod enviroment the system redirect in a page 404

Comment: do you use a custom error handler and can you post its code ? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.3/ScalaErrorHandling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, what you observe is the correct behavior of Play 2.4

In dev mode, 404 are handled by the [devNotFound.scala.html](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages/devNotFound.scala.html) template and yield errors which look like : 
[image]

In prod mode, 404 are handled by the [notFound.scala.html](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/defaultpages/notFound.scala.html) template and yield errors which look like: 
[image]

Notice how the first error lists all the existing routes, while the second doesn't.

If you want another rendering for 404 NotFound errors you will need to create your own error handler as documented in [ScalaErrorHandling](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.3/ScalaErrorHandling)

Comment: Yes, I use custom code, and the problem was in my ScalaErrorHandling. Thanks